# I can't add html rich text to mySQL database from Flex

Tags: mysql, apache-flex

So I want to store richtext in my database created from Flex 3's rich text editor, but I am unable to.

for example this would need to be placed into the database:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Verdana" SIZE="10" COLOR="#0B333C" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">sdfsdfdsfsdfdsf</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

Is it because of all the special characters?

Is it common practice to store formatted text in a database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape such strings before putting them into a query. Alternatively use prepared statements.

Yes, it is a common practice.